# What's the lower bound of the sum $S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^k(1-\frac j n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

If we have

$$
S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^k(1-\frac j n)
$$

What the lower bound of $S(n)$ when $n\to\infty$?

PS: If I didn't make any mistake when I calculate $S(n)$, then it should be $\Omega(n)$.  But I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Is $i=k$ ? (not enough characters)

Comment: Oh yeah, I should be more careful about typos.

Comment: It can be written alternatively as $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!n^{k+1}}$ by expanding the product, if that helps at all.

Comment: @Sasha converted this into an integral and ask how to estimate that integral, there's some answers there too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71447/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can do a bit better then a lower bound.  We can find the main term, which is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$.

Notice that $$\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{k}}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(n-j\right)=\frac{1}{n^{k}}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!}=\frac{\left(n-1\right)_{k}}{n^{k}}.$$ Using this, and the fact that the $k=n$ term is $0$, we can rewrite our series as

$$(n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^{k}(n-k-1)!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n^{n-k-1}}{(n-k-1)!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^{j}}{j!}.$$

Where the last line follows from the substitution $j=n-k-1$. This last sum is the truncated [exponential series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) with $x=n$. Specifically we have that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^{k}}{k!}\sim \frac{1}{2}e^{n}.$$ Thus our series is $$\sim\frac{e^{n}(n-1)!}{2n^{n-1}}.$$ By [Stirling's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_formula), the main term is $$\frac{e^{n}(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}=\sqrt{2\pi n}+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right),$$ so we are able to conclude that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\sim\sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}.$$

Hope that helps,

**Edit:** A factor of two was missing earlier.  Thanks to Didier Piau for pointing this out.

Comment: Eric, nice proof. But we probabilists know that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^k}{k!}\sim\frac12\mathrm e^n$. And Stirling's.

Comment: @DidierPiau: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Two things. First, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^k}{k!}$ is not equivalent to $\mathrm e^n$ but to $\frac12\mathrm e^n$. Second, one should write *Stirling's formula* and not *Stirlings formula*.

Comment: @DidierPiau: Fixed now.  Is there a clean way to get the asymptotic expansion of this series?  To know the precise error terms, or better.   I know it is equivalent to knowing an expansion for the incomplete Gamma Function $\Gamma(n,n)$.

Comment: The term $\frac12\mathrm e^n$ is a direct consequence of the central limit theorem. There is no interpretation as simple as this one (that I know of) for the next terms.

Comment: @EricNaslund: how did you get the summand $\frac{n^k}{k!}$?

Comment: @sigma.z.1980: You are right, that line is a bit brusque.  I added an extra equation in the middle to help clarify.

Comment: @EricNaslund:all clear now, thanks

Comment: @DidierPiau: could you give a hint on how to approach this using CLT?

Comment: @sigma, here is a sketch. The sum from $0$ to $n-2$ is equivalent to the sum from $0$ to $n$. The sum from $0$ to $n$, divided by $e^n$ is $A_n=\mathrm P(X_n\leqslant n)$ where the random variable $X_n$ is Poisson$(n)$. Thus $X_n$ is distributed like the sum of $n$ i.i.d. $Y_k$ Poisson$(1)$. The mean and the variance of $Y_k$ are both $1$ hence the CLT yields $A_n=\mathrm P((Y_1+\cdots+Y_n-n)/\sqrt{n}\leqslant0)\to\mathrm P(N(0,1)\leqslant0)=\frac12$.

Comment: @DidierPiau: excellent! Just 1 question: is $n-2$ 'equivalent' to $n$ in the sense 'equivalent for large $n$?

Comment: @sigma, no, and upon reflection, it is easier to consider $A_n=\mathrm P(X_{n}\leqslant n-2)$ and to note that $A_n=\mathrm P((Y_1+\cdots+Y_n-n)/\sqrt{n}\leqslant-2/\sqrt{n})$ hence $A_n\to\mathrm P(N(0,1)\leqslant0)=\frac12$.

Comment: @DidierPiau: this implies as $n \to \infty \ \ -\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ so I get $\Phi(x)$ anyway.

Answer (score 11):

This is $Q(n)-1$, where $Q(n)$ is a sum that appears repeatedly in Knuth's work and that I mention in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71321/whats-the-asymptotic-lower-bound-of-the-sum-frac-3-2-sum-k-3n-fracn/71359#71359) to your other question.  A slight adaptation of the  argument there shows that the dominant term is (in the notation of the answer) $T_n(0)$, and so we get 
$$Q(n) = S(n)+1 = \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}} + O(1).$$
If you want a more precise asymptotic, you can check out Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming*, Vol. 1 (3rd ed.), Section 1.2.11.3 (again, as I mention in  my other answer).  He gives
$$Q(n) = S(n)+1 = \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{12} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2n}} - \frac{4}{135n} + O(n^{-3/2}).$$

Comment: +1, very nice.  Although I think the $\frac{1}{12}\sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$ term in the last expression should be changed.  (Perhaps the $n$ should be removed?)

Comment: @Eric: Thanks!  Corrected.

Comment: Curious question:  Is the $\frac{1}{12}$ coming from the fact that in Stirling's formula we have the factor $\left(1+\frac{1}{12n}+\cdots\right)$?

Comment: @Eric: Probably.  There's an outline of a derivation using singularity analysis in "[On Ramanjuan's Q-Function](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlGrKiPr95.pdf)," by Flajolet, et al.  See Theorem 2.  I haven't worked through all the details, but right at the end they appear to be using Stirling's approximation to go from (in their notation) $[z^n] L(z)$ to the asymptotic for $Q(n)$.