# The expected max inner product between a random vector and the sum of random vectors

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

**Given:** Fix $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$, we generate $n$ random vectors $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ with $\|X_i\|_2 = 1$.

**We want to compute:** The expected max Euclidean inner product between a random vector and the sum of the random vectors, i.e.,
$$
\mathbb E \max_{i \in [n]} \langle X_i, \sum_{j \in [n]} X_j \rangle.
$$

**What I have tried:**

- When $n = 2$, $\langle X_1, X_1 + X_2 \rangle = \langle X_2, X_1 + X_2 \rangle = 1 + \langle X_1, X_2 \rangle$; $\mathbb E \langle X_1, X_2 \rangle = 0$ due to symmetry, and thus $\mathbb E \max_{i \in [n]} \langle X_i, \sum_{j \in [n]} X_j \rangle = 1$.
- When $n \geq 3$, it becomes unclear to me.
- Intuitively it might get larger as $n$ increases since we have more options, and would approach some limit, possibly related to $\| \sum_{j \in [n]} X_j \|$.
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 3$ and $k = 2$ gives $1.5319441791547532 \pm 0.7104635978561801$.
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 4$ and $k = 2$ gives
  $1.6632600316282025 \pm 0.9042611238131294$.
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 5$ and $k = 2$ gives
  $1.9472506556915035 \pm 0.9787530817053821$.
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 100$ and $k = 2$ gives
  $8.86393808099978 \pm 4.6286431725480295$.
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 100$ and $k = 3$ gives
  $9.083624932218164 \pm 3.8388222137766603$
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 10,000$ and $k = 2$ gives
  $88.64022827148438 \pm 46.3698844909668$.
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 10,000$ and $k = 3$ gives
  $92.19273147896439 \pm 38.86980525584397$.
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 1,000,000$ and $k = 2$ gives
  $886.809001225146 \pm 463.51510862527164$
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 1,000,000$ and $k = 3$ gives
  $921.3826932102985 \pm 388.68428531397456$
- Simulations (1,000,000 trials) with $n = 1,000,000$ and $k = 4$ gives
  $939.8279114022998 \pm 341.27201929744365$
- It looks like the order is near $\sqrt{n}$, and I consequently have a conjecture that it would be something close to $\sqrt{n}$.
- I saw something $0.886$ for $k = 2$, and I know $\sqrt{\pi} / 2 \approx 0.8862$; not sure it is related or not.

  - [Limit of the integral is the square root of pi over 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84590/limit-of-the-integral-is-the-square-root-of-pi-over-2)
  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral
  - I also suspect that it is related to the sphere-cylinder ratio; see, e.g., [Volume of Region in 5D Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50953)

---

As @Sal pointed out, this is related to random walks (see, e.g., [Expected Value of Random Walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103142/expected-value-of-random-walk)), and seemingly
$$
\mathbb E \| \sum_{j \in [n]} X_j \| \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{2n}{k}} \dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})},
$$
which is

- $\sqrt{n} \frac{\Gamma(1.5)}{\Gamma(1)} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sqrt{n} \approx 0.886227 \sqrt{n}$ for $k = 2$ as I suspected,
- $\sqrt{\frac{8}{3\pi}} \sqrt{n} \approx 0.921318 \sqrt{n}$ for $k = 3$,
- $\frac{3}{4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}2} \sqrt{n} \approx 0.939986 \sqrt{n}$ for $k = 4$, and
- indeed approaches $\sqrt{n}$ as $k \to \infty$.

However, this only gives us the asymptotic results as $n \to \infty$, while the cases for small $n$ are still unclear.

Comment: $\sum_j^n X_j$ is a random walk in $k$ dimensions. If I recall correctly, the average absolute value of the random walk is asymptotically $C_k \sqrt{n}$ for some constant $C_k$

Comment: @Sal Thank you! Is it something like this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103142

Comment: Hi, no problem! Yes something like that- however note: the $\sqrt{n}$ scaling should be independent of the dimension so long as the step distributions are 'nice enough', while the constant $C_k$ *may* depend on the step distributions. In your case your steps are uniformly drawn on the $(k-1)$-sphere, while in the linked post the steps are are unit steps on a lattice, so they may differ- in your case it should be possible to evaluate at least $C_2$ explicitly. I'll think about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Large $n$ asymptotics**

Let $S$ be the position of a random walk with steps $X_j$ which are uniformly distributed unit vectors

$$\tag{1}
S=\sum\limits_{j=1}^nX_j
$$

Then using the multivariate CLT the distribution of $S$ as $n\to\infty$ is a multivariate Gaussian

$$\tag{2}
f_S(s)=\frac{\exp\left(-sM^{-1}s/2 \right)}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k|M|}}
$$

where $M$ is the covariance matrix, $|M|$ is the determinant, and $s \in \mathbb{R}^k$. By symmetry we have for the *components* $X_j^m$ of each vector $X_j$

$$\tag{3}
\mathbb{E}(X_j^mX_j^{m'})=\alpha\delta_{mm'}
$$

where $\delta$ is the Kroneckar delta and $\alpha$ is a constant. Using (3) we have $M=\mathbb{I}\alpha$. To find the radial distribution of $r=|s|$ we integrate (2) over the hypersphere $S_{k-1}(r)$ yielding

$$\tag{4}
f_R(r)=\frac{2\pi^{k/2}r^{k-1}}{\Gamma(k/2)}\frac{\exp\left(-r^2/2\alpha \right)}{\sqrt{(2\pi\alpha)^k}}
$$

To determine $\alpha$ we use $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j)=\delta_{ij}$ with (1) to show $\mathbb{E}(S^2)=n$ then compare to $\mathbb{E}(r^2)=\int_0^\infty dr \ r^2 f_R(r)$ using (4). The result is $\alpha=n/k$. Finally we may evaluate

$$\tag{6}
\mathbb{E}(|S|)=\mathbb{E}(r)=\int\limits_0^\infty dr \ r f_R(r) = \sqrt{\frac{2n}{k}}\frac{\Gamma((1+k)/2)}{\Gamma(k/2)}
$$

which is *identical* to the analogous result for the random walk on a lattice!

If we argue that your expression: $\mathbb E \max_{i \in [n]} \langle X_i, \sum_{j \in [n]} X_j \rangle$ is asymptotically equal to $\mathbb{E}(|S|)$ then we have the large $n$ behavior (as done in the answer by @Chris Sanders).

**Finite $n$**

We can expand the quantity $Q$ within the maximum

$$\tag{7}
Q=X_i\cdot S = 1 + \sum\limits_{j\neq i} X_i \cdot X_j
$$

If $L=X_i\cdot X_j$ then $L_j=Y\cdot X_j$ has the same distribution as $L$ with $Y$ a fixed unit vector $(1,0,0,\cdots)$, so that

$$\tag{8}
Q=1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} L_j
$$

I will describe *in principle* how I think we can find the distribution of $\text{max}(Q)$. The [distribution of the dot product of unit vectors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361612/scalar-product-of-random-unit-vectors) is known:

$$\tag{9}
f_L(l)=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{k-1}{2}\right)}\,\left(1-l^2\right)^{\frac{k-3}{2}}\qquad , \qquad |l|<1
$$

To find the distribution of a sum, we can use the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)?useskin=vector)

$$\tag{10}
\varphi_L(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itL})=\int\limits_{-1}^1 dl \ f_L(l) e^{itl}
$$

which a CAS evaluates to hypergeometricFPQ functions$^\dagger$. The characteristic function of $Q$ is

$$\tag{11}
\varphi_Q(t)=e^{it}[\varphi_L(t)]^{n-1}
$$

so that we have

$$\tag{12}
f_Q(q)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dt  \ e^{-iqt} \varphi_Q(t)
$$

from which the CDF $F_Q$ may be found. Then we need to take care of the maximum. **If** it were the case that we draw $n$ times from $Q$, the distribution of the maximum would be

$$\tag{13}
f_+(q)=nf_Q(q)[F_Q(q)]^{n-1}
$$

from which the expectation is

$$\tag{14}
\mathbb{E}(Q_\text{max})=\int dq \ q f_+(q)
$$

which is correct if the draws are independent- I am uncertain if this last part is the correct model for the problem in OP because it seems the $n$ draws from $Q$ are not independent there.

From (12) onwards, I suspect that analytical progress will be very difficult, but at least the steps are possible numerically.

$\dagger$ Actually the result simplifies to Bessel $J$ functions in even dimensions and sums of trig functions in odd dimensions. I do not dwell on this because of the formidable integral awaiting in (12)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is very interesting to see the asymptotic behaviors are the same for Lattice random walks and our unit-vector random walks.
Also, your ideas are very clear, although analytical results might be difficult as you point out!

Comment: No problem, and thank you for your kind words :)

Answer (score 1):

Fix $k$. Asymptotically, how does the expected value of what you want behave as $n$ goes up?

Note that, if you take a small finite area (taking up a small fixed percentage $\epsilon$) of the unit sphere's surface and ask for the probability that all the vectors $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ miss that area, the answer is $(1-\epsilon)^n\to0$.

So for any fixed subdivision of the unit sphere's surface into a finite number of little areas, the probability that each area has at least one of the vectors approaches $1$.

So for larger $n$, it doesn't matter which direction $\sum X_j$ points in, because you can find one of those vectors with a similar direction and do the dot product with that.

The only question is, what is the expectation of $||\sum X_j||_2$?

Comment: Thanks! But the last line is not immediate to me, although that looks true as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Ah sorry yes that was a mistake, but the point still remains that it is just a matter of $\mathbb{E}||\sum X_j||_2$ @VezenBU

Comment: Yes! But seemingly that is a nontrivial problem.

Comment: And this only solves the problem asymptotically.

Comment: MathJax comment: Norms are better typeset using `\|`; for example, `$\mathbb{E} \| \sum X_j \|_2$` yields $\mathbb{E} \| \sum X_j \|_2$.

Comment: Please see my update with @Sal's help. There are existing results on random walks.

Comment: @VezenBU I still have a lot more to learn about probability distributions. Great question overall!