# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm supposed to calculate:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

By using WolframAlpha, I might guess that the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$, which is a pretty interesting and nice result. I wonder in which ways we may approach it.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121099/limit-using-poisson-distribution

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/493435/8348) was merged into the present one.

Comment: [Older question, perhaps merge...] possible duplicate of [Partial sums of exponential series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136996/partial-sums-of-exponential-series)

Comment: Also known as **Dobiński's formula**

Comment: I instantly thought that the limit is $1$, but I was wrong.

Comment: @user 1591719 I've posted a solution that generalizes your question.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

**Edited.** I justified the application of the dominated convergence theorem.

By a simple calculation,

$$ \begin{align*}
e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}
&= \frac{e^{-n}}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} n^k (n-k)! \\
(1) \cdots \quad &= \frac{e^{-n}}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} n^k \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-k}e^{-t} \, dt\\
&= \frac{e^{-n}}{n!} \int_{0}^{\infty} (n+t)^{n}e^{-t} \, dt \\
(2) \cdots \quad &= \frac{1}{n!} \int_{n}^{\infty} t^{n}e^{-t} \, dt \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{n} t^{n}e^{-t} \, dt \\
(3) \cdots \quad &= 1 - \frac{\sqrt{n} (n/e)^n}{n!} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(1 - \frac{u}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^{n}e^{\sqrt{n}u} \, du.
\end{align*}$$

We remark that

1. In $\text{(1)}$, we utilized the famous formula $ n! = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^n e^{-t} \, dt$.
2. In $\text{(2)}$, the substitution $t + n \mapsto t$ is used.
3. In $\text{(3)}$, the substitution $t = n - \sqrt{n}u$ is used.

Then in view of the [*Stirling's formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), it suffices to show that

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(1 - \frac{u}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^{n}e^{\sqrt{n}u} \, du \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$

The idea is to introduce the function

$$ g_n (u) = \left(1 - \frac{u}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^{n}e^{\sqrt{n}u} \mathbf{1}_{(0, \sqrt{n})}(u) $$

and apply pointwise limit to the integrand as $n \to \infty$. This is justified once we find a dominating function for the sequence $(g_n)$. But notice that if $0 < u < \sqrt{n}$, then

$$ \log g_n (u)
= n \log \left(1 - \frac{u}{\sqrt{n}} \right) + \sqrt{n} u
= -\frac{u^2}{2} - \frac{u^3}{3\sqrt{n}} - \frac{u^4}{4n} - \cdots \leq -\frac{u^2}{2}. $$

From this we have $g_n (u) \leq e^{-u^2 /2}$ for all $n$ and $g_n (u) \to e^{-u^2 / 2}$ as $n \to \infty$. Therefore by [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) and [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral),

$$ \int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(1 - \frac{u}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^{n}e^{\sqrt{n}u} \, du = \int_{0}^{\infty} g_n (u) \, du \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u^2/2} \, du = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}. $$

Comment: Your second equation is closely related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71447/large-n-asymptotic-of-int-0-infty-left-1-x-n-rightn-1-exp-x) (which I answered).

Answer (score 189):

> The probabilistic way:

This is $P[N_n\leqslant n]$ where $N_n$ is a random variable with Poisson distribution of parameter $n$. Hence each $N_n$ is distributed like $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ where the random variables $(X_k)$ are independent and identically distributed with Poisson distribution of parameter $1$.

By the central limit theorem, $Y_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}(X_1+\cdots+X_n-n)$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable $Z$, in particular, $P[Y_n\leqslant 0]\to P[Z\leqslant0]$.

Finally, $P[Z\leqslant0]=\frac12$ and $[N_n\leqslant n]=[Y_n\leqslant 0]$ hence $P[N_n\leqslant n]\to\frac12$, QED.

---

The analytical way, completing your try:

> Hence, I know that what I need to do is to find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}I_n$, where
>   $$
> I_n=\frac{e^{-n}}{n!}\int_{0}^n (n-t)^ne^tdt.$$

To begin with, let $u(t)=(1-t)e^t$, then $I_n=\dfrac{e^{-n}n^n}{n!}nJ_n$ with
$$
J_n=\int_{0}^1 u(t)^n\mathrm dt.
$$
Now, $u(t)\leqslant\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}$ hence
$$
J_n\leqslant\int_0^1\mathrm e^{-nt^2/2}\mathrm dt\leqslant\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-nt^2/2}\mathrm dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}.
$$
Likewise, the function $t\mapsto u(t)\mathrm e^{t^2/2}$ is decreasing on $t\geqslant0$ hence $u(t)\geqslant c_n\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}$ on $t\leqslant1/n^{1/4}$, with $c_n=u(1/n^{1/4})\mathrm e^{-1/(2\sqrt{n})}$, hence
$$
J_n\geqslant c_n\int_0^{1/n^{1/4}}\mathrm e^{-nt^2/2}\mathrm dt=\frac{c_n}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^{n^{1/4}}\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt=\frac{c_n}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1+o(1)).
$$
Since $c_n\to1$, all this proves that $\sqrt{n}J_n\to\sqrt{\frac\pi2}$. Stirling formula shows that the prefactor $\frac{e^{-n}n^n}{n!}$ is equivalent to $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$. Regrouping everything, one sees that $I_n\sim\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}n\sqrt{\frac\pi{2n}}=\frac12$.

> *Moral:*
>   The probabilistic way is shorter, easier, more illuminating, and more fun.
>
> *Caveat:*
>   My advice in these matters is, clearly, horribly biased.

Comment: One could simply say that for natural $n$ the median for the Poisson variable is $n$ (which, I believe, is nontrivial), and thus $P[N_n<n]=0.5$ immediately.

Comment: @Did, you are the reason we don't have Nobel prize in mathematics: they are too envious)

Answer (score 66):

Integration by parts yields
$$
\frac{1}{k!}\int_x^\infty e^{-t}\,t^k\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{k!}x^ke^{-x}+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\int_x^\infty e^{-t}\,t^{k-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
$$
Iterating $(1)$ gives
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\int_x^\infty e^{-t}\,t^n\,\mathrm{d}t=e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{2}
$$
Thus, we get
$$
e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{n!}\int_n^\infty e^{-t}\,t^n\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3}
$$
Now, I will reproduce part of the argument I give [here](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/gammaratio.html), which develops a full asymptotic expansion. Additionally, I include some error estimates that were previously missing.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_n^\infty e^{-t}\,t^n\,\mathrm{d}t
&=n^{n+1}e^{-n}\int_0^\infty e^{-ns}\,(s+1)^n\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&=n^{n+1}e^{-n}\int_0^\infty e^{-n(s-\log(1+s)}\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&=n^{n+1}e^{-n}\int_0^\infty e^{-nu^2/2}\,s'\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
where $t=n(s+1)$ and $u^2/2=s-\log(1+s)$.

Note that $\frac{ss'}{1+s}=u$; thus, when $s\ge1$, $s'\le2u$. This leads to the bound
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{s\ge1} e^{-nu^2/2}\,s'\,\mathrm{d}u
&\le\int_{3/4}^\infty e^{-nu^2/2}\,2u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac2ne^{-\frac98n}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
$(5)$ also show that
$$
\int_{s\ge1}e^{-nu^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}u\le\frac2ne^{-\frac98n}\tag{6}
$$

For $|s|<1$, we get
$$
u^2/2=s-\log(1+s)=s^2/2-s^3/3+s^4/4-\dots\tag{7}
$$
We can invert the series to get $s'=1+\frac23u+O(u^2)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-nu^2/2}\,s'\,\mathrm{d}u
&=\int_{s\in[0,1]} e^{-nu^2/2}\,s'\,\mathrm{d}u+\color{red}{\int_{s>1} e^{-nu^2/2}\,s'\,\mathrm{d}u}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\left(1+\frac23u\right)e^{-nu^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}u-\color{darkorange}{\int_{s>1}\left(1+\frac23u\right)e^{-nu^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}u}\\
&+\int_0^\infty e^{-nu^2/2}\,O(u^2)\,\mathrm{d}u-\color{darkorange}{\int_{s>1} e^{-nu^2/2}\,O(u^2)\,\mathrm{d}u}\\
&+\color{red}{\int_{s>1} e^{-nu^2/2}\,s'\,\mathrm{d}u}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}+\frac2{3n}+O\left(n^{-3/2}\right)\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
The red and orange integrals decrease exponentially by $(5)$ and $(6)$.

Plugging $(8)$ into $(4)$ yields
$$
\int_n^\infty e^{-t}\,t^n\,\mathrm{d}t=\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}+\frac23\right)\,n^ne^{-n}+O(n^{n-1/2}e^{-n})\tag{9}
$$
The argument above can be used to prove Stirling's approximation, which says that
$$
n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}+O(n^{n-1/2}e^{-n})\tag{10}
$$
Combining $(9)$ and $(10)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}
&=\frac{1}{n!}\int_n^\infty e^{-t}\,t^n\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac12+\frac{2/3}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}+O(n^{-1})\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment ([he asked, expecting the answer "no"](http://www.montypython.net/scripts/cheese.php))?

Comment: hey rob, sadly the link in your answer is dead :(

Comment: Yeah too many downvoters here :/ I upvoted this. Very Nice answer.

Comment: The asymptotic approximation in $(11)$ can be improved by extending the approximations to get $$ \frac12+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left(\frac23-\frac{23}{270n}+\frac{23}{3024n^2}+\frac{259}{77760n^3}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right) $$ and the big-$O$ term is close to $-\frac1{900n^4}$.

Answer (score 30):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\expo{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n^{k} \over k!}}}
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\expo{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}
\exp\pars{k\ln\pars{n} - \ln\pars{k!}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{\expo{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}
\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{n} - \ln\pars{n!} - {1 \over 2n}\bracks{k - n}^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{\expo{-n}\,{n^{n} \over n!}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}
\exp\pars{-{1 \over 2n}\bracks{k - n}^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{{\expo{-n}n^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{n}
\exp\pars{-{1 \over 2n}\bracks{k - n}^{2}}\,\dd k}
\\[3mm]&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\expo{-n}n^{n} \over n!}\int_{-n}^{0}
\exp\pars{-\,{k^{2} \over 2n}}\,\dd k}
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\expo{-n}n^{n} \over n!}\,\root{2n}
\int_{-\root{n}/2}^{0}\exp\pars{-k^{2}}\,\dd k}
\\[3mm]&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\root{2}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n} \over n!}
\int_{-\infty}^{0}\exp\pars{-k^{2}}\,\dd k}
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\root{2}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n} \over n!}
\,{\root{\pi} \over 2}}
\\[3mm]&=
\half\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n} \over n!}}
=\color{#00f}{\Large\half}
\end{align}

Comment: The second equal sign is a complete mystery. The passage from a sum to an integral also needs justification but it probably holds.

Comment: Would you care answering @Did 's question regarding the second equal sign? I am miffed as well. Thank you, Felix Marin.

Comment: @Did's question has to be answered otherwise this seems to be an suitable answer

Comment: yeah for me too, can you please answer @Did 's question?

Comment: Felix, I'm just curious ... How did you arrive at that second equality?  I don't see it.

Comment: @MarkViola Note that $n^{k}/k!$ has a "sharp" maximum at $k = n$. Roughly speaking, it's a Gaussian. But the sum is just up to $n$. So, it was pretty obvious that the final result must be $1/2$.  When I "went from the sum to the integral" I closely follows  $\texttt{Laplace Method for Sums}$ as explained in the book
$$
\color{#00f}{Analytic\ Combinatorics\ by\ Philippe\ Flajolet\ and\ Robert\ Sedgewick,\ Cambridge\ University\ Press\ 2009}
$$.
$\left(\,\color{#f00}{\texttt{see page 761}}\,\right)$. It's clearer whenever we switch the origin with $k \mapsto n - k$. I didn't do it.

Comment: Is this supposed to justify the various unsubstantiated claims this post relies on? It does not.

Comment: Could you please write more detail about the second equality?@FelixMarin

Comment: @LiTaichi The $\displaystyle\exp$ function has a "sharp maximum" at $\displaystyle k = n \gg 1$. It's sufficient to expand its argument around $\displaystyle k = n$. See my previous comment about Flajolet et. al. book.

Comment: @FelixMarin The two exponents are not equal at all, even if The exp function has a "sharp maximum" at $k=n$, how to prove the second equality is correct?

Answer (score 28):

The sum is related to the partial exponential sum, and thus to the [incomplete gamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8),
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}
&=& e^{-n} e_n(n) \\
&=& \frac{\Gamma(n+1,n)}{\Gamma(n+1)},
\end{eqnarray*}$$
since $e_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k/k! = e^x \Gamma(n+1,x)/\Gamma(n+1)$.
But 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma(n+1,n) &=& \sqrt{2\pi}\, n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right).
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The first term in the asymptotic expansion for $\Gamma(n+1,n)$ can be found by applying the saddle point method to 
$$\Gamma(n+1,n) = \int_n^\infty dt\, t^n e^{-t}.$$
The [higher order](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#E12) terms are in principle straightforward to compute. 
Using Stirling's approximation, we find 
$$e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!} 
= \frac{1}{2} 
+ \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}} 
+ O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
Thus, the limit is $1/2$, as found by @sos440 and @robjohn. 
This limit is a special case of [DLMF 8.11.13](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#E13).

I just noticed a comment that suggests this be done using high school level math.
If this is a standard exercise at your high school, maybe they covered the incomplete gamma function! ;-)

Comment: (+1) I derived this asymptotic expansion [here](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/gammaratio.html) in answer to a question on sci.math. I computed a few terms past $\frac12$:
$$
\frac12+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left(\frac23-\frac{23}{270n}+\frac{23}{3024n^2}+\dots\right)
$$

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks for the link, I'll have a look. By the way, I voted up your nice solution a couple of hours ago. I like your short and sweet derivation of (3).

Comment: @robjohn  As steven gregory says above "I wish you had copied the article here. It seemed small enough. References have a habit of pointing to NULL over time" . Please, could you upload somewhere again? I'm curious about it.

Answer (score 27):

If you'd like to see formal solution using calculus methods check this article http://www.emis.de/journals/AMAPN/vol15/voros.pdf

Comment: I wish you had copied the article here. It seemed small enough. References have a habit of pointing to NULL over time.

Comment: Please try to describe as much here as possible in order to make the answer self-contained. Links are fine as support, but they can go stale and then an answer which is nothing more than a link loses its value. Please read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 13):

I do not know how much this will help you.

For a given $n$, the result is $\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1,n)}{n\ \Gamma(n)}$ which has a limit equal to $\dfrac12$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 8):

**I thought that it might be of instructive to post a solution to a generalization of the OP's question.  Namely, evaluate the limit**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{N(n)}\frac{n^k}{k!}$$

**where $N(n)=\lfloor Cn\rfloor$, where $C>0$ is an arbitrary constant.  To that end we now proceed.**

---

Let $N(n)=\lfloor Cn\rfloor$, where $C>0$ is an arbitrary constant.  We denote $S(n)$ the sum of interest

$$S(n)=e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{n^k}{k!}$$

Applying the analogous methodology presented by @SangchulLee, it is straightforward to show that

$$S(n)=1-\frac{(N/e)^{N}\sqrt{N}}{N!}\int_{(N-n)/\sqrt{N}}^{\sqrt{N}}e^{\sqrt{N}x}\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt N}\right)^N\,dx\tag7$$

We note that the integrand is positive and bounded above by $e^{-x^2/2}$.  Therefore, we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem along with Stirling's Formula to evaluate the limit as $n\to\infty$.

There are three cases to examine.

**Case $1$: $C>1$**

If $C>1$, then both the lower and upper limits of integration on the integral in $(7)$ approach $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.  Therefore, we find

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor Cn\rfloor}\frac{n^k}{k!}=1$$

**Case $2$: $C=1$**

If $C=1$, then the lower limit is $0$ while the upper limit approaches $\infty$ and we find

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n^k}{k!}=\frac12$$

**Case $3$: $C<1$**

If $C<1$, then the lower limit is approaches $-\infty$ while the upper limit approaches $\infty$ and we find

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n^k}{k!}=0$$

---

To summarize we have found that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor Cn\rfloor}\frac{n^k}{k!}=\begin{cases}1&,C>1\\\\\frac12&, C=1\\\\0&, C<1\end{cases}}$$

Comment: This is clever and I wonder if you could take it further: if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n+g_C(n)} = C$, can you characterize $g_C(n)$ at all, along the lines of things like the critical-value results for connectivity in random graph models?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki First, thank you!  Much appreciated.  And yes, I thought about further generalizations, similar to the one you suggest, which should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: On the off chance you haven't seen it before, a further generalization is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n + \lfloor z\sqrt{n}\rfloor} \frac{n^k}{k!} = \Phi(z)$$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.  Your results then follow by direct comparison from $$\Phi(-\infty)  = 0, \Phi(0) = \frac{1}{2}, \Phi(+\infty) = 1$$

Answer (score 7):

*On this page there is a nice collection of evidence.*

I add another proof which also uses the *Stirling formula*.

$\displaystyle e^{-n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!} = e^{-n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{k^k (n-k)^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!} \hspace{4cm}$ e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874271/equality-of-the-sums-sum-limits-v-0k-frackvv-and-sum-limits-v-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{e^k e^{n-k}}{\sqrt{2\pi k (1+\mathcal{O}(1/k))}\sqrt{2\pi (n-k)(1+\mathcal{O}(1/(n-k)))}} $

$\displaystyle = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)}} =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})^2}{2\pi~\Gamma(1)} = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: (+1) Interesting idea.