# Asymptotics of $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{i n^i}{i!}$.

Tags: asymptotics

How can you calculate the asymptotics of $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{i n^i}{i!}$ ?  This sum looks similar to the power series for $e^n$. I have also seen similar problems solved using Poisson distributions  [Limit using Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121099/limit-using-poisson-distribution) for example. However I cannot see how to handle the extra term.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268332/calculate-limit-with-summation-index-in-formula/ Can this help?

Comment: Not only the extra term: you also have $\,n\,$ both in the numerator of the series general tern *and* as the upper limit of the series...

Comment: @DonAntonio That's the same as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/compute-the-limit-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-frac isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{i n^i}{i!}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n^i}{(i-1)!}
= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{ n^{i+1}}{i!}
= n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{ n^{i}}{i!}
$$

Since, as shown in the linked problem,
$$e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}
=\frac12+O(n^{-1/2})
$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{i n^i}{i!}
= n(\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{ n^{i}}{i!}-\frac{ n^{n}}{n!}),
$$

so

$$\begin{align}
e^{-n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{i n^i}{i!}
&= e^{-n}n(\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{ n^{i}}{i!}-\frac{ n^{n}}{n!})\\
&=n(1/2 +O(n^{-1/2})) - n e^{-n}\frac{ n^{n}}{n!}\\
&= n/2 + O(n^{1/2}) - n \frac{(n/e)^n}{\sqrt{\pi}(1+O(1/n)) n^{n+1/2}/e^n}\\
&= n/2 + O(n^{1/2}) - n (n/e)^n/(\sqrt{\pi}(1+O(1/n)) n^{n+1/2}/e^n)\\
&= n/2 + O(n^{1/2}) - n^{1/2}(1+O(1/n))/\sqrt{\pi}\\
&= n/2 + O(n^{1/2})
\end{align}
$$