# A limit involves series and factorials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

Evaluate :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{n!}{{{n}^{n}}}\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{{{n}^{k}}}{k!}-\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{n}^{k}}}{k!}}} \right)$$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem? If you've tried something and it didn't work, it would be useful to know for anyone trying to solve it themselves. Also, if this problem came up in a certain context (i.e. as an exercise in a textbook following a chapter on BLAH), then it may be helpful to a potential answerer to know what this context is.

Comment: Is it $\sqrt{2\pi}$ ??

Comment: @GEdgar I dont know the answer :(

Comment: How about $4/3$.

Comment: Maybe the answers/methods in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/ will provide a hint.

Comment: @GEdgar : I try a large n on the software, I think the limit is 4/3. How did you get that? :)

Comment: It should be doable with the sum of $n$ iid Poisson RVs with parameter 1, but I couldn't solve it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ramanujan proved 
(in S. RAMANUJAN, J. Ind. Math. Soc. 3 (1911), 128; ibid. 4 (1911), 151-152; Collected Papers
(Chelsea, New York; 1962), 323-324)
that

$$e^n/2 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} n^k/k! + (n^n/n!) r(n)$$

where, for large $n$,
$r(n) \approx 1/3 + 4/(135n) + O(1/n^2)$.

I found this in
http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FPEM%2FPEM2_24_03%2FS0013091500016503a.pdf&code=fd828d6902ca6a380244640216120c97
via a Google search for 
"ramanujan exponential series" -
I read Ramanujan's collected works many years ago and remembered this result,
but not its details.

This says that

$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} n^k/k!
&\approx e^n/2 + n^n/n!
-(n^n/n!)r(n) \\
&= e^n/2 + (n^n/n!)(1-r(n))
\end{align}
$

Also,

$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} n^k/k!
&= e^n - \sum_{k=0}^{n} n^k/k!\\
&= e^n - (e^n/2 + (n^n/n!)(1-r(n)))\\
&= e^n/2 - (n^n/n!)(1-r(n))
\end{align}
$

so

$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} n^k/k! - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} n^k/k!
&\approx (e^n/2 + (n^n/n!)(1-r(n)))
- (e^n/2 - (n^n/n!)(1-r(n)))\\
&= (n^n/n!)(2-2r(n))
\end{align}
$

and

$\begin{align}
(n!/n^n)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} n^k/k! - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} n^k/k! \right)
&\approx 2-2r(n) \\
&\to 2-2/3 \\
= 4/3
\end{align}
$.

GEdgar is right! Good guess:)