# Central value of the partial exponential function

Tags: probability-theory, limits, probability-distributions

I need help calculating the central value of the partial exponential function :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-n} \sum^n_{k=0} \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

fd

Comment: Related to a sum of independent Poisson random variables
with parameter 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160352).

Answer (score 1):

I think it goes to 1/2 ... after all, you have half the series :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "half the series"?