# Compare $e^n$ and its first $n$ terms sum

Tags: limits

Compute the limit as $n$ approaches infinity.
$$
 \frac{\sum_{0\le i\le n} \frac{n^i}{i!}}{e^n}
$$

It is somehow between 0 and 1.

Comment: This is old problem : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk/160288#160288