# $ \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^k}{k!} $

Tags: limits

How can be evaluated this limit:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^k}{k!} .$$
Thank you.

Comment: the result is, somewhat amazingly, $1/2$. you can find a discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk

Comment: I would guess 1?

Comment: The reason it's not trivial is that
$
\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{n^k}{k!}
$
approaches $e^n-1$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$ for fixed $n$, but diverges as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for fixed $m$; so the behavior as both $m$ and $n$ go to infinity is tricky.