# Weird limit $\lim \limits_{n\mathop\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^n}\sum \limits_{k\mathop=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim \limits_{n\mathop\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^n}\sum \limits_{k\mathop=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!} $$

I thought this limit was obviously $1$ at first but approximations on Mathematica tells me it's $1/2$. Why is this?

Comment: Very heuristically speaking, stopping the summation at $\frac{n^n}{n!}$ is stopping at the maximal summand, so it is somewhat reasonable to expect that the contribution up to that summand might be about the same as the contribution of the remaining summands.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Good point, indeed ! Cheers.

Comment: This exact same question has been asked before here on this site.

Comment: Well if they made it easy to search for questions then that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It is well-known as the Bernstein limit.

Comment: It is more or less the probability that a Poisson-distributed random variable takes a value less than its mean.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/160248).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160352), it is shown that
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}
&=\frac{1}{n!}\int_n^\infty e^{-t}\,t^n\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac12+\frac{2/3}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}+O(n^{-1})
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake since the summation goes to $n$ and not to infinity; then $$\sum \limits_{k\mathop=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!} \neq e^n$$ In fact $$\sum \limits_{k\mathop=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}=\frac{e^n \Gamma (n+1,n)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$ and so the limit you look for is then the limit of $\frac{\Gamma (n+1,n)}{ \Gamma (n+1)}$ when $n$ goes to infinity and this limit is $\frac{1}{2}$ as Mathematica told you.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if there is an elementary way, without the gamma function.