# Is the sequences$\{S_n\}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $$S_n=e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}$$

Is the sequences$\{S_n\}$ convergent?

The following is my answer,but this is not correct. please give some hints.

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x.$$
then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}=1.$$

Comment: Use the property of limits. Break it into two limits, since they both converge. Your answer should be less than 1.

Comment: @Genomeme: One limit is $0$, the other is $\infty$.  One cannot determine the limit of the product from the product of the limits in this case.

Comment: Some testing with WolframAlpha suggests that the limit is indeed $1$. Can find a bound $\displaystyle\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^k}{k!}$?

Comment: Are you sure @JimmyK4542, because I wrote it in terms for the incomplete gamma function and the limit after factoring out the $e^n$ looks to be $1/2$.

Comment: Yeah, I messed up. The limit is infact $1/2$. See this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4dtr78rs9gnobk/On%20The%20Limit%20of%20A%20Sequence.pdf#

Comment: This question has been asked at least [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248) [times](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733656) [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581125).

Comment: @Genomeme that property only applies to when both limits exist

Comment: The both do, I just realized however, that things get a bit tricky but the idea is essentially the same.

Comment: @Lucian: Why not cast a dupe vote if you know a question already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Ramanujan showed this limit to be $\frac12$.

I gave a reference to this result
in a previous answer of mine,
but I can't find it right now.

Added later:

Here is a reference:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=B04924E79B2361751E7AE86C5AF43688?doi=10.1.1.217.7589&rep=rep1&type=pdf

This is called Ramanujan's Q-function.

Comment: While Ramanujan being able to sum this series is impressive, that hardly explains _why_ it converges...

Comment: He did *not* sum it. He showed that the result is $\frac12 + O(\frac1{n})$.