# Summation of exponential series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series, exponential-function

Evaluate the limit:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}
$$
It is not as easy as it seems and the answer is definitely not 1. 
Please help in solving it.

Comment: can you typeset rather than posting an image?

Comment: A first step would be to guess the limit. What could it be?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the Stolz Cesaro Lemma

Comment: How do you know "the answer definitely is not 1"?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870524)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was not aware that it was a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an event whose frequencies open the Poisson distribution and occurs an average of $n$ times per trial, the probability that it occurs $k$ times in a given trial is

$e^{-n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$.

So, the sum in the limit is the probability that the event (which now must have an integer average) occurs no more than the mean number of times. For large $n$, the Poisson distribution is well-approximated by the normal distribution (this can be made into a precise limiting statement). The normal distribution is symmetric about its mean, so the limit of the sum is the probability that a normally distributed random variable is less than the mean of the variable, namely $\frac{1}{2}$.