# Compute the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\frac{1}{k}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk) problem, how can one compute the following limit:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\frac{1}{k}\quad ?$$

Note that
$$\log x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^k\frac{1}{k},\quad x\ge \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left ( 1-\frac1{n}\right )^k = e^{k \log{(1-1/n)}}  = e^{-k/n + O(1/n^2)} = 1-\frac{k}{n}+O \left ( \frac1{n^2} \right )$$

So as $n \to \infty$,

$$\begin{align}\frac1{\log{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \left ( 1-\frac1{n}\right )^k \frac1{k} &= \frac1{\log{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \left (\frac1{k}- \frac1{n} + O \left ( \frac1{n^2} \right ) \right ) \\ &= \frac{H_n - 1}{\log{n}} +  O \left ( \frac1{n \log{n}} \right ) \\ &= 1 - \frac{1-\gamma}{\log{n}} + O \left ( \frac1{n \log{n}} \right ) \end{align}$$

The limit as $n \to \infty$ is thus $1$.

Comment: (+1) As a matter of fact, we both over-killed the problem since the inequality $$1-\frac{k}{n}\leq\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\leq 1$$ was enough ;)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: perhaps, but still, I still like to understand the error involved as I take the limit.

Comment: Perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

Since:
$$ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k}\frac{1}{k}=\int_{0}^{1-1/n}x^{k-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{k}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-x)^{k-1}\,dx $$
we have:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k}\frac{1}{k}=H_n-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x}\,dx,\tag{1}$$
but since $f_n(x)=\frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x}$ is a positive decreasing function on the interval $\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f_n(x) = n$, we have:
$$0\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x)\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}n\,dx = 1,\tag{2} $$
so the initial limit equals:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{H_n}{\log n}=\color{red}{1}.\tag{3}$$