# Find lim$_{n \to \infty} \sum _{ k =0}^ n \frac{e^{-n}n^k}{k!}$

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

We need to find out the limit of,

lim$_{n \to \infty} \sum _{ k =0}^ n \frac{e^{-n}n^k}{k!}$

One can see that $\frac{e^{-n}n^k}{k!}$ is the cdf of Poisson distribution with parameter $n$.

Please give some hints on how to find out the limit.

Comment: As interesting as your question is, you need to show some of your own efforts to solve the problem before I will consider furnishing any hints.

Comment: Central limit theorem (you should get $½$)

Comment: @heropup, I am not able to understand how to proceed!

Comment: A downvote to this problem is unfair, at least the OP observed something.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/160248)

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160352), it is shown that
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}
&=\frac12+\frac{2/3}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}+O\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good start to try to solve it in a probabilistic way: notice that the Poisson random variable has the reproducibility property, that is, if $X_{k} \sim \text{Poisson}(1)$, $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ independently, then
$$S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n X_{k} \sim \text{Poisson}(n),$$
whose distribution function $F_{S_n}$ satisfies:
$$F_{S_n}(n) = P[S_n \leq n] = \sum_{k = 0}^n e^{-n} \frac{n^k}{k!},$$
which is exactly the expression of interest. Hence this suggests linking this problem to central limit theorem.

By the classic CLT, we have
$$\frac{S_n - n}{\sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, 1).$$
Hence
$$P[S_n \leq n] = P\left[\frac{S_n - n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 0\right] \to P[Z \leq 0] = \frac{1}{2}$$
as $n \to \infty$.