# Computing $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}$ with central limit theorem

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

**Exercise:**

Compute the following limit by using the central limit theorem:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}
$$

**Solution (from textbook):**

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ i.i.d. with $X_i\sim Pois(1)$. Then $\mu=E[X_i]=1=Var[X_i]=\sigma^2$. Further let $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$, thus $S\sim Pois(n)$. With the central limit theorem we get
$$
e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}=
\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-n}\frac{n^k}{k!}=
\sum_{k=0}^n Pr[S_n=k] =
Pr[S_n\leq n] =
Pr\left[
\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}
\leq
\frac{n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}
\right]=\ldots
$$
Now this is the step I don't understand: How does term on the right side of "$\leq$" disappear?
$$
\ldots=Pr\left[
\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}
\leq
0
\right]
\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}
\Phi(0)=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Could you explain me the step in between?

Comment: $\mu=1$ (first line of the solution) so $n-n\mu$ is zero.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/493480/147873 One of the answers solves it using the CLT.

Comment: @GEdgar I can see that $\mu=1$ for each of the random variables $X_i$. However, I thought that the purpose of the fractions inside the probability is to standardize $S_n$ in order to be able to use $\Phi$. So we should take the $\mu$ of $S_n$ (the notation is confusing). In this case isn't $E[S_n]=\mu=n=Var[S_n]=\sigma^2$?

Comment: @GEdgar Now I got you. You subtract the rhs of the inequality, and still use the $\mu$ of the $X_i$ since $E[S_n]=n\mu=n\cdot 1 = n$. An then $S_n$ is perfectly standardized. Thank you!

Comment: @GEdgar Could you post your short sentence as an answer? I'll then mark the question as solved then and leave it for reference.

Comment: @Lucian Not a duplicate, this question asks about a specific step of a proof, not for a proof of the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mu=1$ (first line of the solution) so $n−n\mu = 0$.