# How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+n+\frac{n^2}{2!}+\dots +\frac{n^n}{n!})e^{-n}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, gamma-function

Perform a Taylor expansion of $e^x$ at $x=0$, then
$$e^n=1+n+\frac{n^2}{2!}+\dots+\frac{n^n}{n!}+\int_0^{n}\frac{(n-t)^n}{n!}e^ndt,$$
we get
$$(1+n+\frac{n^2}{2!}+\dots +\frac{n^n}{n!})e^{-n}=1-e^{-n}\int_0^{n}\frac{(n-t)^n}{n!}e^tdt=1-\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^nt^ne^{-t}dt.$$

Therefore, it suffices to prove that $\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^nt^ne^{-t}dt=\frac{1}{2}.$

How to get the desired outcome? I note $\int_0^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt=n!$... Can you give me some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This surely already exists here.  My favorite proof of this uses the Central Limit Theorem.  HERE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1599632/442

Comment: It is not true that $\frac 1 {n!}\int_0^nt^ne^{-t}dt=\frac1   2$ but LHS tends to $\frac 1  2$.

Comment: This question with many solutions, including $\frac{1}{n!}\int_n^\infty e^{-t}\,t^n\,\mathrm{d}t$ ... https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160248/442

Comment: It's worth reading the answers to this on Quora. Especially Alon Amit's. https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-that-displaystyle-lim_-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum_-k-0-n-frac-n-k-k-frac-1-2