# Proving $\lim e^{-n}(1+n+n^2/2!+\cdots +n^n/n!) = 1/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In my probability class we saw an amazing proof using the CLT (central limit theorem), I'm wondering what's a more straightforward way to do this.

Comment: How is the equation related to your question ?

Comment: @callculus I'm asking how to prove it with standard methods.

Comment: The CLT or the equation ?

Comment: @callculus the equation.

Comment: If you mean $\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}\cdot e^{-n}$, then have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk

Comment: @callculus Thanks!