# Evaluating a limit involving summation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, summation

> **Evaluate :**
>
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{e^{n}}\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{n} \dfrac{n^r}{r!}\right) $$

Numerical calculation suggests that the limit should be $\dfrac{1}{2}$. I tried using [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) and [Stolz - Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), but to no avail.

An elementary solution is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will find many interesting answers here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are no elementary solutions there though :( Please don't close my question, I'd like to see if there are elementary proofs of this.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio There are no elementary solutions there though :( Please don't close my question, I'd like to see if there are elementary proofs of this.

Comment: @Henry: to use the Poisson distribution and the Central Limit Theorem is the usual way. An "elementary solution" strongly depends on what you meant by "elementary". I think that Sangchul Lee's answer in the other topic is elementary enough.