# Poisson variables - inequalities of sum these variables

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, independence

1. Let $X_1, X_2$ are independent and both have Poisson distriubution with $\lambda=1$.  Find $P\left(\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}\le 1\right)$
2. Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent and all of them have Poisson distriubution with $\lambda=1$. $\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}\le 1\right)$

**My attemption**:
1.
$P\left(\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}\le 1\right)=P\left(\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}=0\right)+P\left(\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}=1\right)= P\left(X_1+X_2=0\right)+P\left(X_1+X_2=2\right)$
Now, I don't know why we get assumption about independence. After all, I don't need it. We know, that if $X_1 \tilde {} Poiss(a), X_2\tilde{}Poiss(b) $ then $X_1+X_2\tilde {} Poiss(a+b)$.
So, in our case $X_1+X_2\tilde{} Poiss(2)$, hence $X_1+X_2=X3\tilde{} Poiss(2)$
$P(X_3=0)+P(X_3=1)=\frac{2^0}{0!}e^{-2}+\frac{2^1}{1!}e^{-2}=3e^{-2}$

At this moment I am not going to begin **2.** becase I didn't finish **1.**.  In particular I don't understand why assumption about independence is given.
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need the assumption of the independence. The independence is needed to establish the distribution of the sum. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with the Poisson distribution, then $X+Y$ has the Poisson distribution too (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Higher_moments)).

However, if $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily independent, the conclusion no longer holds. Take, for example, $Y=X$. Then $X$ and $Y$ have the Poisson distribution, but $X+Y=2X$ does not have the Poisson distribution anymore. So the assumption of the independence is essential here.

Comment: Thanks for clearing issue with independence.  Can you check my solution for 1. and help to solve 2. ?

Comment: The cause for $Y=2X$ has no Poisson distribution is (for example) that $P(Y=2X=1)  = P(X=1/2) = 0$ . Yeah ?

Comment: @HaskellFun That's right. 1. $$P(X_1+X_2\le 2)=P(X_1+X_2=0)+P(X_1+X_2=1)+P(X_1+X_2=2).$$ 2. Not sure about this one. Are you sure that there are no mistakes in the statement?

Comment: When it comes to 2. - I didn't make a mistake during rewrite task.

Comment: So, in case of **1.**  upper bound is $5e^{-2}$. Yeah ?

Comment: Oh, yeah - not bound :)

Comment: @HaskellFun It turns out that the second part is not that easy. But the probabilistic sollution given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/493480/23249) is really elegant.