# Find limit of sequence $e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n n^k/k!$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I can't deal with finding:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n n^k/k!$$
Have you any idea ?

Comment: Ever heard about the Stirling approximation? I might help you

Comment: You could try to search before asking: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk…