# Limit of Euler Approximation.

Tags: calculus, euler-mascheroni-constant

I was trying to solve some asymptotic behaviour of a statistic and got at the end to this problem:

$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} 
e^{-n}*\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{n^i}{i!} $

Does anyone have any hints or a solution for me to what limit this converges?

Comment: This question is similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk