# Gaussian measure of piece of sphere $S_n(h) := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|x\|_2 \le 1,\;x_1 \ge h\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, special-functions

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $\sigma > 0$, and $h > 0$. Consider a height-$h$ piece of the standard $n$-dimensional sphere, defined by
$$
S_n(h) := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|x\|_2 \le 1,\;x_1 \ge h\}.
$$

> **Question.** What is the value of the integral
>   $$I_{n,\sigma}(h):=\mathbb P_{x \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2 I)}(x \in S_n(h)) = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2}\int_{S_n(h)}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\|x\|^2}dx
> $$

## Observations

- The case, $h=0$ which corresponds to the Gaussian measure of a hemi-sphere, is well-known ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3496441/168758), for example) to equal $$
  I_{n,\sigma}(0) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\gamma(n/2,1/(2\sigma^2))}{\Gamma(n/2)} \sim \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sigma n},
  $$
  where $\gamma(s, x) := \int_{0}^x e^{-t}t^{s-1}dt$ is the lower incomplete gamma function and $\Gamma(s):=\gamma(s,\infty)$ is the usual gamma function.

Comment: The segment your are considering is a spherical cap of an n-dimensional hypersphere. See my answer in this post for calculating the surface area of this spherical cap, with a reference therein, which will help you with your problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238156/

Comment: Thanks for the ref. But in my case this would lead to complicated integrals (complicated in the sense that I'm not quite sure how simplify them using any *special functions* with know properties) of the kind here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3505099/168758