# Determining: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty n^k/k!$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

What is the value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty n^k/k!$ ?

I have tried initially but could not proceed any further. What I have tried is:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty{n^k \over k!}\\
=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{-n}\left[e^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n^k \over k!}\right]$$

I got no clue after this. I am not sure if how that limit can be be determined.

Any kind of help will be welcome.

Comment: $1+n+n^2/2!+....n^{n-1}/(n-1)!\rightarrow e^n$, so the limit is $0$. Where are you having a problem in that?

Comment: How is $1+ n + n^2/2 +.....+n^{n-1}/(n-1)! \to e^n$?

Comment: How did you write $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty n^k/k!\\ =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[e^n-(1+n+n^2/2!+....n^{n-1}/(n-1)!)]$

Comment: @AbishankaSaha Isn't it correct? sum starts at $n$ so.. ?

Comment: Because $e^n=1 + n + n^2 +....+n^{n-1}/(n-1)! + n^n/n! +......$

Comment: Yeah... It is correct... That is what I pointed out that $e^n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}n^k/k!$, he has already used that, but he is aking me how I knew that.

Comment: it seems different

Comment: @daniel Fisher this is not 100% a duplicate . here we have squeed sum

Comment: @GuyFsone $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1 - a_n + O(n^{-1/2}))$ is close enough to $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$.

Comment: @Guy squeed sum?

Comment: @DanielFischer also see that there is a term $\frac{e^{-n}n^n}{n!}$ which require Stirling formula to handle it.

Comment: @GuyFsone So what? You need far heavier tools than Stirling's formula to determine the limit anyway.

Comment: @samjoe it means the rest of the series

Comment: If the $\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n n^k/k! =1/2$ , then i guess this  limit value will be 1/2 too.

Comment: Right, @SouravSarkar. Apart from the term $\frac{n^n}{e^n\cdot n!}$, which tends to $0$ by Stirling's approximation, your sequence is $1-e^{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}$.

Comment: thnaks @DanielFischer ..i got it..appreciated.

Comment: Why the votes to reopen? From the work of the OP, the rest of the question may easily be answered by the duplicate link.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt why not? just close it as soon as it is open . I voted for reopen

Comment: @GuyFsone I merely would like to know some reason that 5 users decided to reopen the question, because surely my own judgement may not be better than 5 others? What wrong is there in asking?

Answer (score 0):

we have  $$e^{-n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}
=e^{-n}\left[e^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^k}{k!}\right]= \left[1+ \frac{e^{-n}n^n}{n!}-e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}\right] $$
By Stirling formula $$ \frac{e^{-n}n^n}{n!}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\pi}}\to0$$
from and from here:[Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk?noredirect=1&lq=1) we have 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}\right] = \frac12$$
thus $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}=1-\frac12$$