# Asymptotics of $e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^k}{k!}\cdot\frac1{n-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Letting 
$$
a_n = \sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^k}{k!}\cdot{\frac1{n-k}},
$$
does anyone know of a simple asymptotic equivalent for $a_n$? Numerical experimentation suggests that
$$
a_n \stackrel{?}\sim \tfrac12\log n.
$$
If we get rid of the $\frac1{n-k}$, there is a simple answer, because
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^k}{k!}=\frac12.
$$
as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk). Throwing in the factor $\frac1{n-k}$ seems to change the asymptotics entirely.

The context is that $a_n$ is result of applying Stirling's approximation to $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n_{(k)}}{kn^k},$ which is the expected number of "cycles" that a random function on a set of $n$ elements to itself has, where a cycle is a set of distinct numbers $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k\}$ for which $f(x_i)=x_{i+1}$. If you replace "random function" with "random bijection," the expected number of cycles is about $\log n$, so if my guess is correct then random functions tend to have half as many cycles as permutations.

Comment: Interesting question! +1

Comment: my calculations are still a bit sketchy and i don't have time to polish them up to make them a proper answer so have decided to upload my notes as an pdf:
https://uploadfiles.io/0pion
Have fun ^^

Comment: ah, and thx again for the wonderful question... :)

Comment: Writing the summation as an exact integral was really slick, thank you :) $\tag*{}$ In case posterity is interested, here is a permalink to @tired 's work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCe0h.jpg

Comment: it is interesting to note that if you place another $n-k-1$ into the denominator the resulting asymptotics is  a constant namely $1$.. do you have a combinatorical interpretation for this?

Comment: most likely, putting $m$ additional factor into the denominator the asymptotics will be $1/(m m!)$

Comment: Reversing the order, your summation is $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n_{(k)}}{n^k}\frac1{k(k+1)}.$ This is asymptotically equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n_{(k+1)}}{n^{k+1}}\frac1{k(k+1)}+\frac{n_{(k)}}{n^k}\frac1n.$ The latter can be shown to be exactly equal to $1$ for all $n$, and has a literal interpretation as the expected number of fixed points of a random function. @tired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we follow exercise 5.2 from *[Asymptopia](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1470409046)* by Joel Spencer and show OP's assumption is correct.

> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{n^k}\cdot\frac{1}{k}\sim \frac{1}{2}\ln n}
> \end{align*}
>
> where $n^{\underline{k}}=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$ denotes the *[falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)*.

A convenient approach is to split the index range of $k$ into *three* parts:

- a small range: $\qquad\quad k<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}$
- a middle range: $\quad\quad \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n} < k < \sqrt{n}\ln n$
- and a large range:  $\ \quad k>\sqrt{n}\ln n$.

> **Small range:** $k<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}$
>
> We write 
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{n^k}=\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)
> \end{align*}
>   and consider the logarithm of the product. Since $$\ln(1-x)=-x+O(x^2)$$ when $x\rightarrow 0$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \ln\left(\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{n^k}\right)&=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\ln\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\\
> &\sim\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}-\frac{j}{n}\sim -\frac{k^2}{2n}=o(1)
> \end{align*}
>   Thus we have
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{n^k}\sim 1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   We obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k}\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{n^k}\cdot\frac{1}{k}}&\sim\sum_{k}\frac{1}{k}\sim\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}\right)\\
> &\sim\ln\sqrt{n}-\ln\ln n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{\sim\frac{1}{2}\ln n}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Medium range:** $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}<k<\sqrt{n}\ln n$
>
> Since $\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{n^k}\leq 1$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k}\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{n^k}\cdot\frac{1}{k}}&\leq \sum_{k}\frac{1}{k}\\
> &\sim\ln\left(\sqrt{n}\ln n\right)-\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}\right)\\
> &\sim \ln \sqrt{n}+\ln\ln n-\ln \sqrt{n}+\ln \ln n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{\sim{2\ln \ln n}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Large range:** $k>\sqrt{n}\ln n$
>
> Here we have $\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{n^k}=o(1)$ and we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k}\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{n^k}\cdot\frac{1}{k}}&=o(1)\sum_{k}\frac{1}{k}\\
> &= o(1)\left(\ln n-\ln \left(\sqrt{n}\ln n\right)\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=o(\ln n)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> We see (2) provides the main contribution compared with (3) and (4) and the claim follows.

Comment: matched asymptotic expansions at work (+1). I have something in the same spirit involving the approximation of an integral instead. Maybe i write it up the next days :)

Comment: @tired: Thanks and I'm interested to see related approaches.

Comment: I love all of your well thought out, carefully formatted answers, thanks Markus!

Comment: @MikeEarnest: You're welcome and many thanks for your nice comment. Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Comment: see my comment to the orignal question, i uploaded some notes---

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so un-applying the Stirling's approximation, we want to find 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n_{(k)}}{n^k}\cdot \frac1k
$$
where $n_{(k)}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$. The general idea is that for small enough $k$,$\frac{n_{(k)}}{n^k}\approx  1$, while when $k$ is large, $\frac{n_{(k)}}{n^k}\approx  0$. We need to find the cutoff point where $\frac{n_{(k)}}{n^k}$ is moderate; then the summation is effectively the sum of $1/k$ up to the cutoff point.

Using Stirling's approximation, 
$$
\log \frac{n_{(k)}}{n^k} =n\log n-n-[(n-k)\log (n-k)-(n-k)]-k\log n+\dots\approx -\frac{k^2}{2n}-\frac{k^3}{6n^2}-\dots
$$
Therefore, when $k\sim \sqrt{n}$, $ \frac{n_{(k)}}{n^k}\approx e^{-1/2}$, and that it drops off exponentially quickly after and before. Therefore, waving hands,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n_{(k)}}{n^k}\cdot \frac1k\approx \sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}}\frac1k\sim \tfrac12\log n.
$$

Comment: Well, I somehow think this answer lacks some rigor. You can improve by rewriting it in formal language.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Your general idea is quite good, so (+1).

Answer (score 0):

First, we reverse the order of summation, then we get ($k\to n-k)$:
$$\sqrt{2\pi n}e^{-n}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{n^n}{(n-k)!n^k}\frac1k$$
$$=\sqrt{2\pi n}e^{-n}n^n\frac1{n!}\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}\frac1k$$
$$=(1+o(?))\sum^n_{k=1} (1+o(?))\frac1k\sim H_n\sim \gamma +\ln n$$

I can’t get the $\frac12$ factor. By the way, the two asymptotic formulae used are well-known, but I don’t know the lower order effect.

Comment: The approximation $\frac{n!/(n-k)!}{n^k}\approx 1$ only holds for small enough $k$, so I think the meat of the proof is showing the cutoff for this fraction becoming small is around $k\approx n^{1/2}$. Then the summation $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!/(n-k)!}{n^k}\cdot \frac1{k}$ is effectively $\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}} \frac1k\sim \log(n^{1/2})=\frac12\log n$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest No. On wikipedia, it clearly states that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma(n)n^a}=1$$ for all $a$.

Comment: @Szeto: Your argument is not sound, since *constant* $a$ is addressed in Wiki.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer $-k$ is a constant here as well, since limit is taken on $n$.

Comment: @Szeto: $k$ varies with $n$, since we have to consider $1\leq k \leq n$.