# Asymptotic behaviour of the $\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! n^k k}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

We can show that $\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! n^k k} = \Theta(\ln(n))$

using the fact that $\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{1}{k} = \Theta(\ln(n))$

and $\frac{n!}{(n-k)! n^k} = \Theta(1)$ when $k=[\sqrt{n}]$.

But is it possible to find the exact constant $c$ such that $\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! n^k k} \sim c \ln{n}$?

Comment: Huh, I asked this same question! See this [excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2810602/177399).

Comment: Thanks, @MikeEarnest!