# Using probability to find value of series - Reference request

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, reference-request

I am seeking for references that talk about probabilistic techniques to calculate the value of serie.

Here on MSE some users have been using probability techniques in order to calculate the value of a serie, instead of using the heavy "calculus machinery".

One may find for example : [Did's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk/493480#493480)

These proofs are quite slick and in my opinion give more intuition on what is going on and why a particular serie converge to this particular value.

That's why I am seeking for references on this subject (ie. using probabilistic techniques to calculate the value of series).

I am also very interested in other examples than the one cited above where the value of a serie is calculate using probability.

Thank you !