# Limit of $\exp(-2n) \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2n)^{k}}{k !}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits

What is the limit of $$\exp(-2n)
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2n)^k}{k !}$$ as $n \to \infty ?$

I am getting the indeterminate form $0 \times \infty$ by applying limit directly. 
I don't find any other way to solve this limit.

Comment: [Related topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk?noredirect=1&lq=1)