# Does the sequence $e^{- (1+\varepsilon)n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(1+\varepsilon)^k n^k}{k!}$ converge? And if so, what is the limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

How to handle
$$a_n := e^{- (1+\varepsilon)n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(1+\varepsilon)^k n^k}{k!}  $$
the analytical way, where $\varepsilon > 0.$

What we obviously know is: $a_n \leq 1$.

If we take $J_n \sim  \gamma (n, n)$ where $\gamma(n,n)$ denotes the gamma distribution, then $a_n = \Bbb P( J_n > 1 + \varepsilon)$. I put the $\varepsilon$ there, because in my intuition $J_n \to 1$. Indeed:

$$J_n \sim \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k \sim \frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k \to 1$$

weakly as $n\to\infty$, where $Y_k \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ independently. So, since $\delta_1 (\partial(1+\varepsilon,\infty))=0$, we have $a_n \to 0$.

But what I want is a analytical approach to this, at best with a bound for $a_n$, e.g. $a_n \leq e^{-\phi (n)}$.

Comment: Are you supposed to know about gamma function**s** ?

Comment: I know not really much about gamma functions. This is not a homework question. The sequence is derived from the gamma distribution: $a_n = \Bbb P( J_n > 1 + \varepsilon)$, where $J_n \sim  \gamma (n, n)$

Comment: It is interesting because $\epsilon$ may have a significant impact. Any upper bound for it ?

Comment: No upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the same probabilistic approach as [this earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk/160288#160288). If $X$ is a $\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ random variable with $\lambda = n(1+\epsilon)$, we can write
$$
P(X<n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(1+\varepsilon)^k n^ke^{- (1+\varepsilon)n}}{k!}.
$$ This equals
$$
P\left(\frac{X-n(1+\epsilon)}{\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}}<\frac{-n\epsilon}{\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}}\right).
$$ By the central limit theorem, $\frac{X-n(1+\epsilon)}{\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}}\to \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in distribution. If $c$ is any fixed constant, then we have
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{X-n(1+\epsilon)}{\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}}<\frac{-n\epsilon}{\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}}\right)\le\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{X-n(1+\epsilon)}{\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}}<c\right)=P(\mathcal{N}(0,1)<c).
$$ By  letting $c\to -\infty$, we get $$
\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{- (1+\varepsilon)n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(1+\varepsilon)^k n^k}{k!}=0.
$$

**EDIT**: Note that $E[e^{tX}]=\exp(\lambda(e^t-1))$ where $\lambda=n(1+\epsilon)$. Observe that for $t>0$
$$\begin{eqnarray}
P(X<n)=P(-tX>-nt)&\le &e^{nt}E[e^{-tX}]\\
&=&e^{nt}\exp(n(1+\epsilon)(e^{-t}-1))\\
&=&\left[\exp(t +(1+\epsilon)(e^{-t}-1))\right]^n.
\end{eqnarray}$$ Note that
$$
[t +(1+\epsilon)(e^{-t}-1)]'|_{t=0}=-\epsilon<0.
$$ This implies there exists $t_0>0$ such that $\exp(t_0 +(1+\epsilon)(e^{-t_0}-1))=e^{-c}<1$. This gives
$$
a_n\le e^{-cn}
$$ for some $c>0$ and hence $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I am interested in an analytical approach. But your representation of $a_n$ suggests that a bound exists, which I am interested in.

Comment: @Falrach Probabilistic method can give an exponential bound of the form $a_n\le e^{-cn}$ for some $c>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$b_n=e^{-(1+\varepsilon)n}\sum_{k=n}^{(1+\varepsilon)n}{\frac{(1+\varepsilon)^kn^k}{k!}}.$$

Then $a_n+b_n \leq 1$, and $$b_n \geq n\varepsilon e^{-(1+\varepsilon)n}\frac{(1+\varepsilon)^nn^n}{n!}$$.

Now, note that for any $k < n$, $$\frac{(1+\varepsilon)^kn^k}{k!} \leq (1+\epsilon)^{-1}\frac{(1+\varepsilon)^{k+1}n^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}.$$

Thus $$a_n < e^{-(1+\varepsilon)n}\frac{(1+\varepsilon)^nn^n}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^n{(1+\varepsilon)^{-k}} \leq \varepsilon^{-2}n^{-1}b_n \leq \frac{1}{n\varepsilon^2}.$$

Comment: I don’t think it is...

Comment: I don't understand your summation bound $(1-\varepsilon)n$

Comment: Where do you see it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $(1+\varepsilon)n$ in the first sum.

Comment: I am summing, if you wish, from $n$ to the floor part of $(1+\varepsilon)n$. Is there an issue?

Comment: Okay, that is how I interpreted it. For small $\varepsilon$ the floor part of $(1+\varepsilon)n$ is $n$. So $b_n$ would be zero, or not?

Comment: For small $n$, yes indeed. But we are considering the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. For bigger $n$ this isn't a problem.

Comment: So I have to interpret the $n\varepsilon $ in the beginning of the lower bound for $b_n$ also as the floor part of $n\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes. You can replace it with $2/n\varepsilon^2$ when $n\varepsilon >2$ if you don’t want floor parts.