# How to determing the convergence of $\sum_{x=1}^\infty (e-(1+\frac{1}{x})^x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty (e-(1+\frac{1}{x})^x)$$
I wrote a python script to add up the first few thousand terms and the series does not seem to converge, but I have no idea how to prove this **efficiently**.(I would prefer if the solution did not just involve using a series test and then using l'hopital's rules several times)

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\sum_{x=1}^\infty [e^x - (1+x^{-1})^x]$?

Comment: Your sum does not converge!

Comment: This obviously does not converge as the RHS term converges to the finite value $e$ whereas $e^x$ is unbounded so the terms do not tend to zero and hence the sum cannot converge.

Comment: I'm wondering if this sum was intended to be $e-(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$

Comment: Perhaps is $\displaystyle\sum e^n-(1+\frac{n}{x})^x$ for some $x$!

Comment: I guess as a further question, is that supposed to be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty [e^{x} - (1+x/n)^n]$, a sum which also diverges but less trivially so.

Comment: Something in the "similar" spirit: [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160248/9464). Not a duplicate, of course.

Comment: Sorry I clarified the question

Comment: @herbsteinberg I'm not the OP, but I think it is alright the way it is. The sequence $$a_n = e - \left(1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n$$ does approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$, so it is reasonable to ask if $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n $ converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x
&=\exp{\left(x\ln{\left(1+\frac1x\right)}\right)}\\
&=\exp{\left(x\left(\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+O\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)\right)\right)}\\
&=\exp{\left(1-\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)}\\
\end{align}$$

Using the series expansion above (valid for $x\ge1$) we have
$$\begin{align}
e-\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x
&=e-\exp{\left(1-\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)}\\
&=e\left(1-\exp{\left(-\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)}\right)\\
&=e\left(1-\left(1+\left(-\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)\right)\\
&=e\left(1-\left(1-\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)\right)\\
&=e\left(\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{e}{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\\
\end{align}$$
$$\sum_{x=1}^n\left(e-\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\right)=\sum_{x=1}^n\left(\frac{e}{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)=\frac{e}2H_n+O(1)$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number and $O$ denotes [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). As $\lim_{n\to\infty}H_n$ is well known to diverge, then our sequence also diverges.

Comment: How did you arrive at that series expansion(I am not familiar with the big O notation)

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the workings out of the series expansion, but as for the big-O notation, I've provided a link to the Wikipedia article on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

$$
e - \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} - \sum_{n=0}^x \frac{x!}{n!(x-n)!}x^{-n} = \sum_{n=2}^x \frac{1}{n!}\left[1 - \frac{x!}{(x-n)! x^n}\right] + \sum_{n=x+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}
$$
The $n=0,1$ terms drop out because they are zero. Note that every term in these sums is positive, since $x^n(x-n)! > x!$ for all $1 < n \le x$. In particular, that means that if we drop every term except $n=2$, we get
$$
e - \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x > \frac{1}{2x}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\sum_{x=1}^\infty \left[
e - \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right] > \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2x} = \infty,
$$
and the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make use of the fact that $e\gt(1+1/N)^N$ for any positive integer $N$.  Then, letting $N=2n$ and using the algebraic identity $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+\cdots+b^{n-1})$, we have

$$\begin{align}
e-\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n
&\gt\left(1+{1\over2n}\right)^{2n}-\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n\\
&=\left(\left(1+{1\over2n}\right)^2-\left(1+{1\over n}\right) \right)\left(\left(1+{1\over2n}\right)^{2(n-1)}+\cdots+\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^{n-1} \right)\\
&\gt{1\over4n^2}\left(1+\cdots+1\right)\\
&={1\over4n}
\end{align}$$

and thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(e-\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n\right)\gt{1\over4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n}$$

which diverges.

It's worth noting that the algebraic steps above show that

$$\left(1+{1\over N}\right)^N
\lt\left(1+{1\over2N}\right)^{2N}
\lt\left(1+{1\over4N}\right)^{4N}
\lt\cdots\left(1+{1\over2^kN}\right)^{2^kN}\lt\cdots$$

which *proves* the fact that $e\gt(1+1/N)^N$ for any positive integer $N$, since $2^kN\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$.