# Finding solution of $\frac{e^x}{2} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, approximation

I am looking to find a numerical solution to the equation:

> $$\frac{e^x}{2} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$

where $k$ is of the order of $10^7$, and the solution is accurate to at least 2-3 decimals. It is not hard to show that the equation has exactly one positive solution (just differentiate and use induction).

Roughly, it measures how good of an approximation is the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ upto $k$ terms. Thus, as $k$ increases, we can expect $x$ to increase as well, as the accuracy of the expansion increases farther from the origin. We can get an lower bound on $x$ by the Taylor's theorem on $e^x$, as the remainder here is $\frac{e^x}{2}$, so $\frac{e^x}{2} \leq \frac{e^x}{k!}x^k$ which implies $\sqrt[k]{\frac{k!}{2}} \leq x$. Thus by Stirling's formula, we see that the lower bound is almost $\frac{k}{e}$.

My first idea was to use binary search, by simply computing the entire function and checking its sign. I coded it up in Python, but unfortunately, it only works for values of $k$ upto about $1000$. Beyond that, the values get too big to fit in its numeric data type. I tried many other ways, like Newton's method which did not work out, amongst other things. The main problem here is I can't find a way to avoid computing the entire function (which will overflow). I have tried hard to solve it, but couldn't do it so hopefully you all can help.

Comment: If you can compute the solution for $k=1$ to $k=1000$, maybe one can look at this series and then make an extrapolation to $k=10^7$? If you can get a rigorous argument for the growth rate of this function it should be quite accurate.

Comment: The Taylor bound should be $e^x-\frac{e^\xi}{k!}x^k$. Using $\xi=x$ gives $e^x\left(1-\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [exponential sum function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFunction.html). Letting $k=n+1$ and using identities with the incomplete Gamma function and the [regularized Gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html), the problem can be rewritten as solving:

$$Q(n+1,x)-\frac12=0$$

The problem is then tractable, as the main problem is numerically evaluating the function due to a significant amount of cancellation and the fact that $e^x$ simply becomes $\infty$ near the root in double precision as you have said.

We can now evaluate this using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GammaRegularized%5Bn%2B1%2Cx%5D-0.5+where+n+%3D+10000000+and+x+%3D+10000000) in the above form. In only a few secant iterations, we find that [the desired root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GammaRegularized%5Bn%2B1%2Cx%5D-0.5+where+n+%3D+10000000+and+x+%3D+10000000.666666668) for $n=10^7$ is then

$$x=10000000.666666668\dots$$

---

It is interesting to note that the root seems to remain between $n$ and $n+1$, which makes sense when working out the Stirling approximation with the Taylor remainder.

Comment: Regarding the last remark, the following inequality appears in the DLMF: $$\frac{\Gamma(n,n)}{\Gamma(n)} <\frac{1}{2} < \frac{\Gamma(n,n-1)}{\Gamma(n)}$$ for any positive integer $n$. Since $\Gamma(n,x)$ increases monotonically with $x$, we conclude that the desired root of $\frac{\Gamma(n+1,x)}{n!}=\frac12$ indeed lies in the interval $(n,n+1)$. (This is in terms of the incomplete Gamma function rather than the regularized Gamma function.)

Comment: Furthermore, the fact that the root seems to be roughly $x=n+2/3$ appears to be directly related to the following statistical fact: For a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$, the mean and median are approximately $\mu=\lambda$ and $\nu = \lambda+1/3$ respectively. More precisely, one has the sharp bounds $\mu-\ln 2\leq \nu < \mu+1/3$ as discussed in this paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2160389. (This paper furthermore indicates a connection to work by Ramanujan---quite a pedigree!)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the cool finds.

Comment: @Semiclassical. Thanks for the fantastic link !

Comment: Theorem 1.2 in https://doi.org/10.1090/mcom/3391 yields a complete asymptotic expansion for the solution for large $n$.

Answer (score 2):

From a numerical point of view, I should write the problem as : find the zero of
$$f(\epsilon)=\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (k+1,k+\frac 23+\epsilon}{k!}\right)+\log (2)$$ A quite detailed numerical analysis shows that
$$\epsilon=\frac{8}{405\, k}-\frac{15}{1196 \,k^2}+\frac{7}{1170\, k^3}-\frac{1}{722
  \, k^4}$$ is a quite good approximation (all parameters being highly significant). So, as an approximation
$$\color{blue}{x=k+\frac 23+\frac{8}{405\, k}-\frac{15}{1196 \,k^2}+\frac{7}{1170\, k^3}-\frac{1}{722 \, k^4}}$$

Applied to the case $k=10^7$ used by @Simply Beautiful Art, the above formula gives
$$x=\color{red}{1.000000066666666864197518322}39\times 10^7$$ while the exact solution is
            $$x=1.00000006666666686419751832256\times 10^7$$

**Edit**

From a formal point of view, the first iterate of Newton method gives
$$x_1=x_0+\frac{e^{x_0}}{ x_0^{k}}\, \Gamma (k+1,x_0)\,\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (k+1,x_0)}{k!}\right)\qquad \text{with}\qquad x_0=k+\frac 23$$

Computing $\epsilon$ for $5 \leq k \leq 10000$ (step size = $5$), a polynomial regression gives (after rationalization of the coefficients)
$$\epsilon=\frac{8}{405\, k}-\frac{15}{1198\, k^2}+\frac{8}{1299 \,k^3}-\frac{2}{1007\,   k^4}$$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +0.019753 & 2.76 \times 10^{-8} &   \{+0.019753,+0.019753\} \\
 b & -0.012521 & 1.42 \times 10^{-6} &   \{-0.012524,-0.012518\} \\
 c & +0.006159 & 1.81 \times 10^{-5} &   \{+0.006124,+0.006194\} \\
 d & -0.001987 & 5.87 \times 10^{-5} &   \{-0.002102,-0.001871\} \\
\end{array}$$

We could even do better using Halley method which would give
$$x_2=x_0+\frac{2 f(x_0) f'(x_0)}{f(x_0) f''(x_0)-2 f'(x_0)^2}$$
$$f'(x_0)=-\frac{e^{-x_0} \left(x_0\right)^k}{\Gamma
   \left(k+1,x_0\right)}\qquad f''(x_0)=\frac{e^{-2 x_0} x_0^{k-1} \left(2 e^{x_0} \Gamma (k+1,x_0)-3 x_0^{k+1}\right) } {3 \Gamma (k+1,x_0)^2 }$$

**Update**

Thanks to the [link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2160389?read-now=1&seq=7#page_scan_tab_contents) @Semiclassical provided, the already existing solution is
$$\epsilon=\frac{8}{405\, k}-\frac{64}{5103\, k^2}+\frac{2944}{492075
  \, k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$

Continuing my work, it *seems* that the next term could be close to
$$- \frac{149}{113289\,k^4}$$

Comment: This is one of those times when I'd rather not try using derivatives. Not only is the expression somewhat messy to work with, but the resulting expressions suffer from being hard to compute, as several of the terms are quite large, which was the main issue.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. Is it a positive or negative comment ? Cheers ;-)

Comment: Negative I suppose? :P

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160352) says
$$
\left[\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}-\frac12e^x\,\right]\overset{\substack{x=n\\[2pt]\\}}=\frac23\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}+O\!\left(\frac{e^n}n\right)\tag1
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^m}{\mathrm{d}x^m}\left[\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}-\frac12e^x\,\right]
&=\left[\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}-\frac12e^x\,\right]-\sum_{k=n-m+1}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{2a}\\[3pt]
&\overset{\substack{x=n\\[2pt]\\}}=\frac23\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}-m\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}+O\!\left(\frac{e^n}n\right)\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Applying Taylor's Series, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n+x)^k}{k!}-\frac12e^{n+x}
&=\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(\frac23-m\right)\frac{x^m}{m!}+O\!\left(\frac{e^n}n\right)\tag{3a}\\
&=\left(\frac23-x\right)\frac{e^{n+x}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}+O\!\left(\frac{e^n}n\right)\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, as $n\to\infty$, it looks as if $x=n+\frac23$ is pretty close.

---

**Improvement**

As noted in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk/160352#comment7369453_160352) to the answer cited above,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}-\frac12e^x\overset{\substack{x=n\\[2pt]\\}}=
\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left(\frac23-\frac{23}{270n}+\frac{23}{3024n^2}+\frac{259}{77760n^3}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\tag4
$$
$(4)$ extends $(1)$ and part of $\text{(2a)}$. To extend the other part of $\text{(2a)}$, we use [Stirling Numbers of the First Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind):
$$\newcommand{\stirone}[2]{\left[{#1}\atop{#2}\right]}
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\tag{5a}\\
&\overset{\substack{x=n\\[2pt]\\}}=\frac{n^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\tag{5b}\\
&=\frac{n^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\sum_{j=0}^k\stirone{k}{k-j}\left(-\frac1n\right)^j\tag{5c}\\
&=\frac{n^n}{n!}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\sum_{k=j}^{m-1}\stirone{k}{k-j}\left(-\frac1n\right)^j\tag{5d}\\
&=\frac{n^n}{n!}\left(\binom{m}{1}-\frac{\binom{m}{3}}n+\frac{3\binom{m}{5}+2\binom{m}{4}}{n^2}-\frac{15\binom{m}{7}+20\binom{m}{6}+6\binom{m}{5}}{n^3}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\tag{5e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: the right side of the difference in $\text{(2a)}$
$\text{(5b)}$: expand as a product
$\text{(5c)}$: apply Stirling Numbers of the First Kind
$\text{(5d)}$: switch order of summation
$\text{(5e)}$: use Stirling Number identities to sum the terms for $0\le j\le3$

Summing $\text{(5e)}$ against $\frac{x^m}{m!}$ gives 
$$
\frac{n^n}{n!}e^x\!\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6n}+\frac{3x^5+10x^4}{120n^2}-\frac{15x^7+140x^6+252x^5}{5040n^3}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\tag6
$$
Taking the reciprocal of Stirling's Formula gives
$$
\frac{n^n}{n!}=\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left(1-\frac1{12n}+\frac1{288n^2}+\frac{139}{51840n^3}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\tag7
$$
Combining $(6)$ and $(7)$, subtracting from $(4)$ summed against $\frac{x^m}{m!}$, gives, via Taylor's Theorem,
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n+x)^k}{k!}-\frac12e^{n+x}\\
&=\frac{e^{n+x}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left(\vphantom{\frac{x^2}{n^2}}\right.\frac{2-3x}3+\frac{90x^3+45x-46}{540n}\\
&-\frac{756x^5+2520x^4+420x^3+105x-230}{30240n^2}\\[3pt]
&-\frac{3240x^7+30240x^6+52164x^5-7560x^4-630x^3+2919x-3626}{1088640n^3}\left.\vphantom{\frac{x^2}{n^2}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\tag8
\end{align}
$$