# Calculate the limit of a sequence: $\frac{ a_n(y_n) }{e^{y_n}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $(a_n)$ be the Taylor development of the exponential function as follows:
\begin{eqnarray} 
a_n(x) = \sum^{n}_{k = 0} \frac{x^k}{k!} 
\end{eqnarray}

Let $(y_n)$ be a positive and strictly monotone sequence with limit $+\infty$.

**Question**
Can we prove the following limit ?

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n \to +\infty } \frac{ a_n(y_n) }{e^{y_n}}  =  1 
\end{eqnarray}

If not possible, can we prove that at least this limit $\lim_{n \to +\infty } \frac{ a_n(y_n) }{e^{y_n}}  > 0$ ?

You can find a French version of this question here: [Calculer la limite de la suite suivante: $\frac{ a_n(y_n) }{e^{y_n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642599/calculer-la-limite-de-la-suite-suivante-frac-a-ny-n-ey-n)?

Comment: We have $$\frac{a_n(n^3)}{e^{n^3}} \le \frac{1+n^2+\cdots+\frac{n^{3n}}{n!}}{1+n^2+\cdots+\frac{n^{3(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}}\le\frac{(n+1)\frac{n^{3n}}{n!}}{\frac{n^{3(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}}\to 0.$$

Comment: @InfiniteMath I highly recomend you to take a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160248/1122499) that proves that, when $y_n=n$, the limit is $1/2$.

Comment: Thank you Danka very much for your input. Really wonderful!

Comment: There is post that proves something quite similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: There is also this post that proves another similar result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339131/asymptotics-of-partial-exponential-sum-sum-limits-k-0a-n-fracnkk?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Another good idea here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764175/lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-e-2n-sum-k-0n-frac2nkk?rq=1

Comment: And here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166061/the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-fract-nnen-where-t-nx-is-the-taylor-po