# The limit of an integral (with statistical backgrounds)

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I would like to compute the following limit of an integral $$I=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_0^n\frac{x^n\text{e}^{-x}}{n!}\text{d}x$$
which I encountered in a statistics problem. I can easily do this using Gamma distribution and Central Limit Theorem:

> Consider a random variable $X_n$ with PDF $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n\text{e}^{-x}}{n!}$. From the properties of Gamma distribution, it can be decomposed into exponential distributions, $X_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ where $X_k\sim\text{Exp}(1)$. Now let $F_n(x)=\text{P}(\frac{X_n-n}{\sqrt n}\leq x)$; from Central Limit Theorem, $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}F_n(x)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\text{P}\left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k -n}{\sqrt n}\leq x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x\text{e}^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}\text{d}t$$ Plugging $x=0$ in gives $I=\frac 1 2$.

Nevertheless, I would like to know if there are any *pure math* methods for solving this (that don't involve anything statistical). The integral itself, [from Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5En%20e%5E%28-x%29%2Fn%21%20from%200%20to%20n), is $$\int_0^n\frac{x^n\text{e}^{-x}}{n!}\text{d}x=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)-\Gamma(n+1,n)}{n!}$$
which doesn't seem to be very useful (it's just rewriting this integral in a Gamma function form). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The rewriting of the integral in terms of the incomplete Gamma function does have one interesting implication: Since $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ for nonnegative integer $n$, the desired limit amounts to showing $$1-\frac{\Gamma(n+1,n)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\to \frac12,$$  or $\Gamma(n+1,n)/\Gamma(n+1)\to 1/2$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it is as *pure math* as you'd wish but here goes. Let:
$$
I_{m,n} = \int_0^m \frac{x^ne^{-x}}{n!}\text{d}x
$$
Using a simple integration by parts yields, for $n>0$:
$$
I_{m,n} -I_{m,n-1} = -\frac{m^ne^{-m}}{n!}
$$
Furthermore:
$$
I_{m,0} = \int_0^m e^{-x}\text{d}x = 1 - e^{-m}
$$
Then:
$$
I_{m,n} = I_{m,0} + \sum_{k=1}^n (I_{m,k} - I_{m,k-1})
$$

$$
I_{m,n} = 1 - e^{-m} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{m^ke^{-m}}{k!}
$$

Which, when setting $m$ to $n$:

$$
I_{n,n} = \int_0^n \frac{x^ne^{-x}}{n!}\text{d}x =  1 - e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}
$$

That was the rather easy part. You can then conclude using the result of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk) (where most of the answers essentially go back the other way, so really you're just better off just picking up from where your integral appears).

Comment: Wow that's a good method. +1