# Convergence rate about a limit concerning the Poisson CDF.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, poisson-distribution, rate-of-convergence

The CDF of a Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$ is
$$
P(n;\lambda)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}.
$$
As $n$ goes to infinity, the CDF would certainly approach 1.

Now, consider the case when the rate parameter is $\xi n$ with $\xi\in(0,1)$ being a given constant.
According to the last answer in [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk), the following limit should be 1:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(n;\xi n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n\xi)^ke^{-n\xi}}{k!}=1.
$$
Is it possible to check the convergence rate of the above limit?
More specifically, I wonder whether the convergence rate is faster than $n$, i.e., whether $n[1-P(n;\xi n)]=O(1)$?

I checked using software that the convergence rate is faster than $n$, but I don't know how to show it rigorously. Can anyone provide some hints and insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$S_n= \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n\xi)^ke^{-n\xi}}{k!}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1,n \xi )}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$

If you consider the "easier" case
$$T_n=\frac{\Gamma (n+1,(n+1) \xi )}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$

Now, consider Nemes's paper (have a look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#iii) at formula $8.11.7$, truncating the summation to $k=2$, taking logarithms, using Stirling expansion, it seems that at the first order (hoping no mistake)
$$\log(T_n) \sim n (1-\xi +\log (\xi ))$$

Hoping that this could help.