# The limit of $e^{-n}\Big({1+\frac n{1!}+\dots+\frac {n^n}{n!}}\Big)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove the limit:
\[
\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\Big({1+\frac n{1!}+\dots+\frac {n^n}{n!}}\Big)=\frac12.
\]

There is a solution based on some knowledge of probability:

> Let $X_1,\dots,X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d}}\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(1)$ and $Y_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$. Then $Y_n\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(n)$, and by central limit theorem we have
>  \[
>  \mathbb P(Y_n\leqslant n)=e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-\frac12x^2}\, dx=\frac12.
>  \]

I am looking for a more direct solution, but failed to got it yet. After using Taylor expansion and Stirling's formula, I tried to prove
\[
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\Big(\frac n{n+1}+\frac{n^2}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\dots\Big)=\frac12.
\]
This one has not been proved successfully. It looks quite different from the original one but I am also intersted in its solution staring from it independently.

Comment: You can find some non-probability approaches here: [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk)

Comment: And you should ask your second question in a separate post.

Comment: The duplicate target (and more identical questions) can be found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7De%5E%7B-n%7D%5CBig(%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%20n%7B1!%7D%2B%5Cdots%2B%5Cfrac%20%7Bn%5En%7D%7Bn!%7D%7D%5CBig)%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I didn't expect this problem is duplicate (and even discussed in such great depth!). Thank you very much.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you! I couldn't find this problem before I asked. This really helps.

Comment: @ImbalanceDream: You are welcome. See also [How to search with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969).

Comment: @ImbalanceDream Welcome! $\ddot{\smile}$