# Is there any easier way to get the asymptotic value of this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

@Mike Spivey has proved in another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71321/whats-the-asymptotic-lower-bound-of-the-sum-frac-3-2-sum-k-3n-fracn/71359#71359), that

$$
S(n) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{n!}{k (n-k)! n^k} = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k n^k} \sim \frac{1}{2} \log(n).
$$

But that proof is out of my ability to understand. So, is there more elementary way to prove it?

Comment: I have made edits that I think reflect Mike's original answer in the other question. Maybe I am alone in this, but when I see $1/2\log n$, I don't instinctively think/read *one-half times log of n*...

Comment: @cardinal: No you aren't; either `\frac{}{}` or parentheses should really have been used to begin with to banish ambiguity.

Comment: Hi ablmf, what is the definition of $n^{\underline{k}}$ ?

Comment: @Leandro: [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol#Alternate_notations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a rough argument. Filling in the details should be elementary, but challenging. I find myself reusing several ideas from [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64971/).

The sum is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} (1-1/n)(1-2/n)\cdots (1-k/n)$$
As discussed in the earlier answer,
$$(1-1/n) (1-2/n) \cdots (1-k/n) \approx e^{-k^2/(2n)}.$$

So the sum is roughly
$$\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k} e^{-k^2/(2n)} = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{k} e^{-(k/\sqrt{n})^2 /2}.$$

This is a Riemann sum approximation (with interval size $1/\sqrt{n}$) to the integral
$$\int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x} e^{-x^2/2}$$
Let $[x<1]$ be $1$ for $x<1$ and $0$ for $x \geq 1$. Then the integral is
$$\int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^{1} \frac{dx}{x} + \int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2/2} - [x<1]}{x} dx.$$
The first integral is $(1/2) \log n$.  The second approaches $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2/2} - [x<1]}{x} dx$, which is convergent.

So our final integral is $(1/2) \log n + O(1)$. I don't want to make too strong a claim about how much accuracy is lost in all the approximations, but one should be able to work it out.